# Как правильно преобразовать первую букву строки в заглавную?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
function ucFirst(str) {
  var b = str.substring(1);
  var a = str.charAt().toUpperCase();
  console.log(a + b);
}

ucFirst('вася');
```

Напишите функцию `ucFirst(str)`, которая возвращает строку `str` с заглавным первым символом, например: ***"вася"***;

Такое решение в настоящем проекте будет норм или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант сделать так:

```js
function ucfirst(str) {
   var at = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   return at + str.substr(1, str.length-1);
}
console.log(ucfirst('вася'));
```

Comment: str.length-1 зачем ?

Comment: @xes, чтобы сказать функции всю длину сразу, без подсчета внутри функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.ucfirst=function()
{
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.slice(1);
}
```

`console.log('вася'.ucfirst());`

Comment: Это будет медленно работать.

Comment: @And Что именно `slice` или `prototype`?

Comment: @And В общем да, вместо `slice` лучше `substr` использовать, но если и вдоваться в детали, то Ваш ненужный костыль `str.length-1` в совокупности с  `substr` будет всё равно медленней, так как длина строк и массивов в JS вычисляется динамически при каждом обращении.

Comment: Где пруфы билли? Мне нужны пруфы. О чем вы вообще говорите, какой динамический подсчет. Строки в js не изменяемые и длина хранится сразу, без каких либо перерасчетов, [длину строки нельзя изменить](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3d616214(v=vs.94).aspx)  Ко всему `str.length - 1` - это индекс последнего символа. Я согласен, что можно не писать, но тогда `substr` будет собирать и считать сам до конца `length`, что на доли мс будет медленнее, чем дать понять какая вся длина строки.

Comment: @And По поводу динамического характера свойства `length` я извиняюсь. Прочитал об этом не помню уже где, там в цикле `for` не рекомендовали в блоке сравнения ставить в качестве условия `str.lenght` и предлагали сохранять его в блоке инициализации и сравнивать его уже из этой переменной. Пруфов этому, пересмотрев MDN и книгу Фленигана я обнаружить не смог и даже обнаружил обратное.

По поводу `str.length - 1` это тот случай, когда программист не должен думать за компилятор/интерпретатор, а просто следовать документации по работе с ним.